# unable to render material select element properly in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron, materialize

I am new to electron and I recently started trying electron and I am facing certain issue with materialized elements. The select element is properly rendered when I open the Html file in the browser, but when I run the HTML file from electron it's not rendering properly, [electron rendering of the select element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoyVQ.jpg). The following files are main.js and index.html respectively. Please help me resolve this issue.

```js
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
} = require("electron");

require("electron-reload")(__dirname);
let window;
function createWindow() {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    title: "App",
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  window.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css">
  <title>App</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>What do you think?</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
      <option value="dont">I Don't Know</option>
    </select>
    <label>A Demo of Material Select</label>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function($){
      $(function(){
        // Plugin initialization
        $('select').not('.disabled').formSelect();
      });
    })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the same issue with bootstrap v5. Were you able to find a solution?